# Selecting an RDS DB for newly created secrets in AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, secret-manager

While I try to create a new secrets for RDS using AWS CLI, I couldn't find the way where I could associate my secrets to RDS DB on creation itself.I have gone through the AWS CLI(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/secretsmanager/create-secret.html) and wasn't able to find a way for its association.

Do I need to do this step manually by logging into the console or could this be automated in some way?
Could anyone please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The association is only based on the **form of the secret-string**. For the RDS the forms are listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/reference_available-rotation-templates.html#sar-template-mysql-singleuser).

For instance, for mysql the form of the `secret-string` is as follows:

```
{
  "engine": "mysql",
  "host": "<required: instance host name/resolvable DNS name>",
  "username": "<required: username>",
  "password": "<required: password>",
  "dbname": "<optional: database name. If not specified, defaults to None>",
  "port": "<optional: TCP port number. If not specified, defaults to 3306>"
}
```

Thus,  to create the secret for mysql using CLI:

1. Create file called `mydb.json` (example):

```
{
  "username": "admin",
  "password": "asdf435325gfdg",
  "engine": "mysql",
  "host": "database-2.cba4sasaubqv.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
  "port": 3306,
  "dbInstanceIdentifier": "database-2"
}
```

2. Execute:

```
aws secretsmanager create-secret --name mysql-info  --secret-string file://mydb.json
```

The more confusing CLI part begins when you want to enable an automatic secret rotations. I will just leave a link for that (it also has CLI info) if you are interested in this as well:

- [Enabling Rotation for an Amazon RDS Database Secret](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/enable-rotation-rds.html)